# Was Fermat's last theorem ever a Conjecture?

Tags: mathematics

As we all know, Fermat has stated [his theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem) at the corner of a book. That is far from the standard way of representing a theorem. He said he had a proof which we never saw. So before it was proven true by Andrew Wiles was it assumed that Fermat actually had a proof and thus its a THEOREM or it was called a CONJECTURE till it was proved by Andrew Wiles.

Comment: I highly doubt that people thought [Fermi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrico_Fermi) had a proof of the theorem...

Answer (score 4):

Mathematicians speculate that Fermat may have made a subtle error in a proposed "proof" such as for example the error of assuming unique factorisation of algebraic integers which was the basis for a 19th century incorrect proof apparently by Lamé.

It is considered unlikely that Fermat had a correct proof.  The odds are against it, given the number of people who have worked on the problem and continue to do so :-)

Comment: Another argument against the likelihood of Fermat having a proof: he never mentioned it in public.